# Reinstate object reference after JSON.stringify-ing and JSON.parse-ing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Consider the piece of code below.

I my AngularJS app, when I fill the $scope.records' objects with categories[0], they are linked together and I can show the category property in my view:

JS:

```
$scope.categories = [{
    title: 'Category 1'
}, {
    title: 'Category 2'
}];

$scope.records = [{title: 'New record', category: $scope.categories[0]}];
```

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="record.category" ng-options="category.title for category in categories"></select>
```

But: When I stringify the array of objects and then parse it again...

```
var json = JSON.stringify($scope.records);
var parsedJson = JSON.parse(json);

$scope.records = parsedJson;
```

...I 'loose the link' and I'm essentially creating a copy, thus the category does not show up as 'selected' because:

`$scope.records[0].category === $scope.categories[0]` evaluates to false.

Any idea to get around this?

Might be a really stupid question, in that case: I'm sorry :-)

Comment: To make a copy of an object you can use angular.copy http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of mapping the complete category object into the record, map it's `id` or `name` and it would work every if you serialize it to json and back

```
$scope.records = [{title: 'New record', category: $scope.categories[0].id}];
```

The select expression becomes

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="record.category" ng-options="category.title for category.id in categories"></select>
```

Comment: That did the trick! Didn't want to get into id's since it would bulk my code a bit when adding new categories but I suppose this is the only way. Thanks for your help mate!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
   $scope.records = parsedJson;
});
```

In short in your example angularjs is not aware that something has been changed and you have to notify it with `$scope.$apply` call. Check http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope

This example is very similar to case when we're trying to assign to the scope a variable fetched via ajax call outside angularjs, for instance with pure jquery get method. In this case we have do something like (pseudo code):

```
$.get("/api/something.json", function(results) {
  $scope.$apply(function() {
     $scope.records = results;
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried this piece of code but it got me an error: $digest already in progress. Thoughts?